# Why is this foreach loop not working?

Tags: php, api, loops, foreach

I am writing a PHP script that will get all URLs matching a specific format from a designated website, and then use the SharedCount API to calculate how many times each URL has been shared on LinkedIn.

I can't reveal the website with all of the URLS, but in the script below, I know that the API works, and I know that the regex pattern I set up ("MyRegex is just a placeholder -- I can't fully share it without writing what the website is) works. I modified the script to just echo results of $matches[0], and I got the list I needed. So all that's good.

The problem is that when I run this script, I am being told that each URL has been shared on LinkedIn 0 times, when I KNOW that's not true. This makes me think the script is somehow looping through only one URL (maybe the first one), which does have 0 shares, and then showing that share value for all of them.

Any ideas why this may be happening, and how to fix it?

```
<?php

  $apikey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  $html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');

    preg_match_all ("MyRegex", $html, $matches);

    foreach ($matches[0] as $url) {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://free.sharedcount.com/?url=" . urlencode($url) . "/&apikey=" . $apikey); 
    $counts = json_decode($json, true);
    echo "This page has " . $counts["LinkedIn"] . " " . "LinkedIn shares" . "<br>";
    }       

?>
```

More information about the API I am using: http://admin.sharedcount.com/documentation.php

Comment: add some basic debugging `print_r($matches);`

Comment: I agree with @Dagon. There isn't enough information here for us to accurately help. We don't know the structure of the result array (which is dependent on the pattern). Your best shot is to observe the structure for yourself and recode your loop based on your findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for helping me think through this problem.

In the end, it turned out to be much, much simpler than I expected. I modified the foreach loop to only display the list of URLs that I was querying, and then viewed the source. Turns out, my preg_match_all was also pulling in `</loc>` (I am scraping an XML sitemap), but I couldn't have known that unless I viewed the source (the page was showing the clean URLs, just as I wanted).

When I modified my regex function, all was fixed.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

Your for loop should look like:

```
 foreach ($matches as $url => $value) {
    $json = file_get_contents("http://free.sharedcount.com/?url=" . urlencode($url) . "/&apikey=" . $apikey); 
    $counts = json_decode($json, true);
    echo "This page has " . $counts["LinkedIn"] . " " . "LinkedIn shares" . "<br>";
}
```

The foreach is going to loop through all the array values.

In the above example, $url should be the url, and the $value should be strings matched by the pattern.

However, you should still do a print_r($matches) and look at source to get a clear view of your array structure, and determine how you want to parse it exactly.

Reference php documents with a foreach loop example: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Another possible solution is to assign the $matches[0] to another array that is no longer a multidimensional array.

```
$urls = $matches[0]
```

then declare your for loop like:

```
foreach ($urls as $url){
```

Update:: 
Since we have verified the issue is not the foreach loop, I would suggest, dumping the json data you're receiving from the API with print_r.

Also, I noted in the API docs they use a rawurlencode() instead of a urlencode() like you are doing. These two will encode the urls differently, as you can see in the php docs here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php and here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php.

Try switching that to rawurlencode() first, and if that doesn't solve your problem, start debugging the json response, and the results of json_decode().

Comment: I believe I actually AM dealing with a multidimensional array, since I am using preg_match_all

Comment: @Dustin @Dagon `preg_match_all` does indeed return a multidimensional array in most uses. Refer to http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: i know, but unless he displays the array, hes just guessing. just trying to teach basic debugging

Comment: @DustinParham I don't think this answer is correct yet. There are still too many unknowns as to the format of the array based on the pattern. As a nitpick, you should remove the "declaring the [0] will confuse the foreach loop" as that isn't true. PHP is fully capable of iterating over secondary dimensions.

Comment: Running print_r($matches) returns: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => MyMatchedString1 [1] => MyMatchedString2 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => MatchedSubString1 [1] => MatchedSubString2))

Comment: @blakeo_x Fair point, made the edit. According to the documents, $matches[0] should in fact be an array of matched strings. and $matches[1] is an array of pieces of the string matched by sections of the preq_match. I think the structure of the array is fairly standard.

Comment: @LukasPleva then the loop you specified in your original question is valid (if by "MyMatchedString", you mean the URLs). My guess is that the problem lies in the returned JSON not being of the format you expect. Debug it next. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @LukasPleva Give my last suggestion a try.

Comment: @blakeo_x yup, MyMatchedString corresponds to the URL

Comment: Have to agree with @blakeo_x then. Problem is somewhere else. Does the echo out, echo out once for every matchedString that the print_r($matches[0]) contains? If so, it's not your forloop.

Comment: If it helps: If I do $urls = $matches[0]; foreach ($urls as $url) { echo $url; }, it spits out all of my URLs

Comment: Here's more information about the API I am using: https://admin.sharedcount.com/documentation.php

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've provided in response to Dustin's answer, plus the API documentation, it appears the structure of your loop is not the problem. My suggestion is to take one of the URLs you are attempting to check, put it into [the test page provided by the API site](https://admin.sharedcount.com/dashboard.php), and verify the API is able to pull the counts you expect to see.

If that page returns zeroes where you expect differently, the problem lies in the API logic itself, you aren't providing a page that is scrape-able, or the URL you provide is different from the one people are sharing (many pages have a multitude of ways to arrive at them). If it returns what you expect, I'd guess that your request from your code is being denied for some reason. Common reasons for this happening are:

- Your API key is incorrect/expired
- There is a request limit associated with your API key that has been reached
- Your request is malformed

Try coding a solution that works for a single URL you statically provide. Once you have that working, work backwards until you have your loop structure again.